# MD simulation - Water Vapour

Tags: molecular-dynamics

I wanted to know the procedure of starting up a water vapor calculation in LAMMPS. I want to calculate properties of water (i.e. in vapor state) at a higher temperature than 100 Celsius. Currently I am setting up the simulation same as liquid water but with the density of $0.001\, \text{g/cm}^3$.  Initially my box has 1000 times less molecules than that of liquid water and it has 800 atoms in $200\times200\times200\ \mathring{\text{A}}^3$ box.

I am running this simulation in LAMMPS 2014. I have tried all ensembles (NVT, NPT and NVE) with various time intervals. The simulation starts running for only NVE but for a very small time-step of $0.001\, \text{fs}$. If I increase the time interval, the simulation stops with an error "Out of range atoms - cannot compute PPPM". The error also comes if I run a NPT simulation.

I would appreciate if anybody can help me with this problem. I can also attach my input scripts and data file if needed.

Comment: I would think that compressibility of water vapor would lead to different dynamics than the approximate incompressibility of liquid water.  It's hard to tell from the short description of your project what connection this may have with the error message emitted.

Comment: It also seems like water vapor would have much too high velocities for the molecular forces to be all that useful. Are you sure MD is the right model here?

Comment: @hardmath - Yes, the compressibility is an issue. I tried to look for different potential parameters for water vapour but I was not able to find anything. The error message just means that molecules are moving out of box and I have seen people use the same model for water-vapor two phase dynamics.

Comment: @BillBarth Yes, the velocities become very and the molecules move out of the box. The thing I want to do these computations at nanoscale level, so other than MD I don't see any other method to simulate my system. If you have any idea to perform these calculations at nanoscale level, please tell me.

Comment: I'm assuming you figured something out for this based on the age of the question, but if you have similar problems in the future, you may want to ask on Matter Modeling SE.